# Дженерики. Ошибка Error:(2, 25) java: generic array creation

Tags: java, generics

Почему при такой записи компилятор не ругается:

```java
private int arr[] = new int[16];
```

А при такой ругается? ⇒ `Error:(2, 25) java: generic array creation`

```java
class MyList<T> {
    private T arr[] = new T arr[16];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что `int` - это примитивный тип, а в качестве `<T>` ожидается объект. В вашем случае:

```
class MyList<T> {
    private T arr[] = (T[]) new Object[16];
}
```

Посмотрите конструктор класса **ArrayList**, в нем инициализация внутреннего массива происходит по аналогичному алгоритму. Примерно так:

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
}
```